# How to drop rows of 2 separate pandas Data Frame simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these Df:

features

`print(features.iloc[: , :5])`

```
          TSPAN6      DPM1      CFH      GCLC     NFYA
0    108.0135  204.8328  85.2727   67.2226  31.8547
1    186.7056  160.0243   4.2396   53.5222  42.5699
2     72.4201   99.3833   4.1743   22.9030  23.6429
3     73.9806  130.6741  52.5459   39.5808  62.8356
4     76.9549  254.8962   3.8422   14.1576  33.3147
..        ...       ...      ...       ...      ...
423   48.8054   95.8473  54.5920  113.4654  29.6582
424   51.9074  143.1845  29.6633    6.2267  29.7790
425   31.3020  101.8710  11.2932   12.8149  25.0943
426    8.8482  219.0544   8.5334    8.8949  26.2537
427   49.3555   81.8803  28.2460   39.3479  13.2189
```

```
   features.shape
(428, 4931)
```

Target:

```
    y.head()
0     Gr II
1    Gr III
2     Gr II
3     Gr IV
4     Gr II
```

```
   y.shape
(428,)
```

I want to drop all `rows` with `Gr II` with the corresponding `rows` in the `features df` so that I will only have `Gr III and` Gr IV in `target df`

```
the output should also be 2 separate DF's
```

implementing it on a particular Df is ok. but, In this case I have 2 separate DF and its a bit difficult for me.

any suggestion(s) on how I can implement this on both DF's simultaneously?

regards

Answer (score 0):

```
**create same column names in both df**



features.insert(loc=0, column='row_num', value=np.arange(len(features)))

target.insert(loc=0, column='row_num', value=np.arange(len(target)))
```

*join the 2 DF*

```
df1 = pd.merge(target, features, on='row_num', how='left')
```

*drop GradeIII* assuming `BlcaGrade` is the column name that has `GradeIII`

```
drop_GradeIII = df1[ df1['BlcaGrade'] == 'Grade III'].index
df1.drop(drop_GradeIII, inplace = True)
```